# Structured properties in protocol

Tags: swift

Say I have

```
protocol Theme {
    var headerTextColor: UIColor { get }
    var footerTextColor: UIColor { get }

    var headerImage: UIImage { get }
    var footerImage: UIImage { get }
}

struct DarkTheme: Theme {
    var headerTextColor: UIColor { return ... }
    var footerTextColor: UIColor { return ... }

    var headerImage: UIImage { return ... }
    var footerImage: UIImage { return ... }
}

struct LightTheme: Theme {
    var headerTextColor: UIColor { return ... }
    var footerTextColor: UIColor { return ... }

    var headerImage: UIImage { return ... }
    var footerImage: UIImage { return ... }
}
```

So instance that implements this protocol access properties as follows

```
lightTheme.headerTextColor
darkTheme.footerImage
```

What I'd like to achieve is to somehow ***structure*** these properties  so that last snippet would look lik

```
lightTheme.color.headerText
darkTheme.image.footer
```

Comment: Why use a protocol here at all? `Theme` looks exactly like a struct. Anything that needs a theme would just have a `theme` property rather than a bunch of sub-properties. Then it's trivial to lay this out any way that you like.

Comment: @RobNapier I've changed my question a bit.

Comment: Why have seperate `DarkTheme` and `LightTheme` structs? There's nothing stopping me from setting a `LightTheme` instance's properties to dark colors and images. As Rob says, you just need to use a single struct for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I'd like to achieve is to somehow **structure** these properties so
>   that last snippet would look like
>
> ```
> lightTheme.color.headerText
> darkTheme.image.footer
> ```

You've already emphasized "structure" yourself in this request: simply create custom structures that will yield a property tree of your liking. E.g.

```
/* set these properties to 'var' in case you plan to
   mutate them beyong initialization */

struct Colors {
    let headerText: UIColor
    let footerText: UIColor
    // ...
}

struct Images {
    let header: UIImage
    let footer: UIImage
    // ...
}
```

As already pointed out in the comments to your question, there is seemingly no difference between the *types* `DarkTheme` and `LightTheme` other than the values of their common properties. This means you probably just want to define a single `Theme` type, and have *instances* of this type that describe different themes (e.g. a dark and light theme).

Using the help structures as above, e.g.:

```
struct Theme {
    let color: Colors
    let image: Images
    // ...
}

// two Theme instances
let darkTheme = Theme( /* initialize with some "dark" theme 
                          values for the member properties
                          of Theme */ )

let lightTheme = Theme( /* some "light" theme */ )

// access subproperties of each theme (which are as initialized)
darkTheme.color.headerText
lightTheme.image.footer

/* if you want to mutate these themes on the fly, simply set
   the instance properties of Theme and the help structures to
   mutables ('var') */
```